# Unable to unmount, permission denied:

Tags: ubuntu, mount, gnome, sshfs, unmounting

I'm having trouble unmounting a mounted remote filesystem in the nautilus UI. (ubuntu gnome)

It says permission denied.
Am I doing right by mounting this way ? :

```
somepass | sshfs remoteuser@host:path mnt/somefoldername -p remoteport -o password_stdin
```

This works, but obviously, it is mounted with a user on the remote computer.
I've got the feeling this is why my user is then not allowed to unmount this mount point. Is that right? what's the right way to mount or unmount then?

To unmount, I have to force it by sudoing my user :

```
sudo umount -f somemountpath
```

This is very unhandy as I have to do it a lot of times, I did create keyboard shortcuts to mount, I'd like to be able to unmount with the UI.

Answer (score 10):

You could try `fusermount -u somemountpoint`.

edit:
As sshfs makes use of the FUSE (Filesystem in Userspace) kernel module, one should use fusermount to unmount FUSE filesystems, at least in userspace.

Comment: Please add a bit of explanation what this does and why you think this might fix the problem

Comment: but this is not in the user interface...

Comment: @VincentDuprez: I think it would be worth the 10 seconds needed to test it though.

Comment: There is a bit of a misunderstanding here, yes it works, but my question is how to achieve this in the UI, how to mount it in such way I can unmount it in the UI

Comment: Just upvoted this answer though beause it addresses the ownership issue and has no reason for being downvoted as it is.

Comment: @VincentDuprez:  If you created a keyboard shortcut to mount it, why don't you do the same to unmount it?

Comment: @JuliePelletier Becaus the first shortcuts runs a bash script that loads the hundreds of sshfs available mounts at that specific time, mount names are unique, I could write a bash scripr and ask for the name with zenity, but as the button already exists in nautilus, I'd like to use it.

Comment: In case any one else comes here, this _is_ a known bug; just one no one seems to care much about. https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=607706

Answer (score 0):

You have to make directorys to mount the drives:

```
mkdir /home/someuser/Remote_Disks
mkdir /home/someuser/Remote_Disks/hdd_1
```

Do this for as many drives a you need to sshfs mount.

I wrote a script to help with mount/unmount:

```
#!/bin/bash
if mount | grep /mnt/hdd_$1 > /dev/null; then
    notify-send "The rsfHDD number $1 is no longer mounted. "
    fusermount -u /home/someuser/Remote_Disks/hdd_$1
       else
           sshfs someuser@$2:/mnt/hdd_1 /home/someuser/Remote_Disks/hdd_$1
           notify-send "The rsfHDD number $1 is now mounted. "
       fi
```

> On my remote server the drives are mounted at /mnt/hdd_1 /mnt/hdd_2 ext...

Then I created launchers that pass 2 arguments to that script: argument $1 is what drive number and argument $2 is someuser@IP/web address of the server.

Then you click to mount and click to unmount.